# Groovy Script to remove the xml declaration and parent nodes and display only childnodes

Tags: groovy

I am trying to transform xml using groovy script but failing, Any help will be highly appreciated
My input is xml is below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<rsp stat="ok" version="1.0">
<result>
<total_results>700</total_results>
<emailClick>
<id>993</id>
<created_at>2023-02-14 00:00:10</created_at>
</emailClick>
<emailClick>
<id>995</id>
<created_at>2023-02-14 00:00:10</created_at>
</emailClick>
</result>
</rsp>
```

My output will display only childnodes  without xml declaration and parent xml tags

```
<emailClick>
<id>993</id>
<created_at>2023-02-14 00:00:10</created_at>
</emailClick>
<emailClick>
<id>995</id>
<created_at>2023-02-14 00:00:10</created_at>
</emailClick>
```

I tried getting the nodelist using xmlparser and then convert that into string but it is resulting in error

Comment: Where did `total_results` go in your output?

Comment: Also, xml transformation won't help much, as your required output is not xml.  So you're going to have to parse the xml, get just the nodes you want (no idea from the question how this is decided), serialize that to a string, and then delete the first and last lines of the string output.  Then you should have your unparseable desired result

Comment: Thanks tim_yates for responding. I need to parse the xml input and filter only the emailClick nodes . using groovy script, could you please provide the code snippet